# android studio memory leak testing for existing android application in mobile or xamarin android projects

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have searched through online, still not able to get the clear idea to perform memory leak test in android studio for xamarin.android projects or already deployed app in the device?

Please help on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**PREPARATION:**

1) Download ["Eclipse Memory Analyzer"](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php)

2) Find Android Device Monitor. Bundled with Android SDK and can be found at "Android-SKD/tools/monitor". You can find out location of that folder by opening Xamarin, pressing CMD + , and selecting SDK Locations.

[image]
[image]

3) Find Heap Snapshot converter (from Android to Java). Bundled with Android SDK and can be found at "Android-SDK/platform-tools/hprof-conv"

[image]

**CAPTURE:**

1) Install application with debug mode on device

2) Connect device to PC and launch monitor (2 step at preparation)

3) Launch the application and find it by application ID in devices.

[image]

4) Press Update Heap (icon to the right from bug icon)

5) Do stuff that you think makes leaks

6) Press Save Heap (icon to the right of start) and save it to the drive

**RETRIEVER RESULTS:**

1) Convert android Heap to Java Heap

1.1) Launch terminal

1.2) Locate Heap Shanpshot converter (hprof-conv) (3 step at preparation)

1.3) drop hprof-conv to terminal

1.4) drop Android heap, and then, drop it next and rename it. It will create correct copy in the same location with chosen name

```
android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/hprof-conv raw.hprof converted.hprof
```

[image]

2) Open Eclipse Memory Analyzer (1 step at preparation)

3) Import acquired Head Dump

[image]

3) Select Leak Suspects Report

[image]

4) View results

[image]

Comment: Thanks. These steps are list out suspects only.  Can we list out , which class files (with the name of C# classes) occupies the memory from this. And can i identify the memory leak after the application stops and the from which classes the memory leaks.

Comment: I think not because the android studio does not know anything about C# runtime. You can try Xamarin Profiler, but it requires Enterprise licence.

Comment: Is there any other tool to test memory leak for installed application in android mobile?